# forming a proof involving a partition and a relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

Okay so I have spent an hour on this problem and still cannot find a way to start this proof. Any help would be nice.

Suppose $P$ is a partition of a set $A$. Define a relation $R$ on $A$ by declaring $xR\, y \iff x,\, y \in X$ for some $X \in P$. Prove $R$ is an equivalence relation on $A$.
Then prove that $P$ is the set of equivalence classes of $R$.

Comment: Recall the definition of equivalence relation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation#Definition

Comment: Start by proving that the relation is reflexive, symmetric and transitive.

Answer (score 0):

> "...and still cannot find a way to start this proof."

Let $x\in A$.

We have $A=\bigcup_{X\in P} X$ since $P$ is a partition of $A$. So $x\in X$ for some $X\in P$ and we can conclude that $xRx$. Proved is now that $R$ is a reflexive relation.

Well, this is a start of this proof, right?

Now go on with proving that $R$ is symmetric ($xRy\implies yRx$) and transitive ($xRy\wedge yRz\implies xRz$).

If that's done then try to prove that $\{y\in A\mid xRy\}$ coincides with the unique $X\in P$ that satisfies $x\in X$.